# EAC: Batch edit track title in metadata to use track number

Tags: software

I'm ripping a CD audiobook in Exact Audio Copy (EAC) and want the metadata track titles to reflect the track number (which reach >100, e.g., Track 001, Track 002, ... Track 099...) Is there any way to automate this within Exact Audio Copy (EAC) without manually renaming each track title?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a one-step solution to do this, but here are two two-step proposals:

### Solution 1:

- Create a file containing all numbers from 1 to 999 formatted on 3 digits like this:

  ```
  001
  002
  003
  ...
  998
  999
  ```

  then select the whole text (usually `Ctrl+A`) and copy it to clipboard (usually `Ctrl+C`).
- In EAC, go to menu ***Database*** > ***Get CD Information From*** > ***Clipboard*** (`Shift+Ctrl+V`).

  As a consequence, the titles of each track should be replaced with its corresponding number, and EAC will save titles as metadata.

**How to create such a file?**

- Use a spreadsheet software such as *LibreOffice Calc*, *Microsft Excel* or *Google Sheets*.
- Use a programming language, for instance in python ([try it online](https://repl.it/HXNg/0)):

  ```
  for n in range(1,1000):
      print "{:03d}".format(n)
  ```

### Solution 2:

- In EAC, go to menu ***EAC*** > ***EAC Options...***, then open tab ***Filename*** and type in ***Naming scheme*** input :

  ```
  whatever-you-want/%tracknr3%
  ```

  This way, the name of the files produced by EAC will be equal to the track number on 3 digits plus a file extension.
- Then, in a metadata capable audio player/editor (I recommend *Foobar2000* for this purpose), fill titles from filename (in *Foobar2000*, right-click on selection then choose ***Properties***, then click ***Tools*** > ***Automatically fill values...***, and use `File names` as ***Source*** and `%title%` as ***Pattern***).

Answer (score 1):

I too ran into this dilemma and struggled with an effective yet time/work efficient solution.  Not fully understanding the previous two solution examples, I created my own using a very simple yet tremendously powerful (and 100% FREE) Windows automation scripting app called "Auto Hot Key".

Basically, you install the app, then you create fairly simple text script files (with the Windows extension of .ahk rather than .txt), which are then triggered to run with any hotkey that you choose.

For example, this is my script for updating the "Title" field names to match the corresponding "Track Numbers" in EAC:

```
^1::
InputBox, tt, Total Tracks, How many tracks does this disc contain?
InputBox, ft, Starting Track Number, What's the number of the First Track?

Sleep 5000

Loop %tt% {

Send {End}{Backspace 2}0%ft%{Enter} 
++ft

}
```

Note - The 0 in the line "Send {End}{Backspace 2}0%ft%{Enter}", is used to add a leading third digit as padding for audiobooks that contain more than 100 total tracks. If your particular audiobook contains less than 100 total tracks and you wish to shorten all concerning numbering, then simply remove the 0 from your script.

So, for example the answers for the SECOND disc of a typical audiobook disc containing 16 total tracks, would be 16 and 32.

A word of caution here - to END or EXIT a running script (which in some cases can be EXTREMELY difficult if not impossible), perform the following in in the System Tray of your Windows Taskbar:
Left-click 1, Right-click 2, and then Left-click 3.

[image]

So first I RUN the script by double-clicking on the .ahk file, then I ACTIVATE the script by pressing CTRL+1, then I answer the two question dialog prompts, and then (WITHIN 5 SECONDS) I MUST click TWICE (with a slight PAUSE) on the FIRST track name in order to be in the correct place and state for the script to work.

Please note that the Auto Hot Key support documentation is quite extensive and by simply reading it you will quickly learn how to craft and more importantly truly understand your own scripts.

I truly hope that you find my comments both helpful and educational and perhaps FUN!

Take care and God bless,
Rob